# When binding a ListView using an ItemsSource, what is the correct way to indicate to the ListView that one or more items are already selected?

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a WPF form which includes a ListView and the following bindings:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableItems}" SelectionMode="Extended">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Data From" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Started}" Width="150" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Data To" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Finished}" Width="150" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The ViewModel's SelectableItems property returns an ObservableCollection of SelectableObject items where the SelectableObject inherits from ListViewItem.

The challenge we are having is as follows. When the view is initialized, one or more items in the SelectableItems collection may have their IsSelected property set to true. When the view is shown, visually each item appears to be in the correct selection state. Unfortunately, it appears that the "current selection" information is not being fully communicated to the ListView itself. The expected operation upon performing a simple single click on a non-selected item is that any currently selected items are deselected and the single clicked item then becomes the only item with IsSelected set to true. This does not appear to be happening. Instead the newly clicked item is added to the set of previously clicked items... but only the first time. All subsequent single click operations operate as expected.

Is there something else that needs to be done during initialization to correctly initialize the ListView's expectations concerning the currently selected items?

Comment: SelectableObject should *not* be derived from ListViewItem. Instead it should be a pure data item class in your view model.

Comment: Fair enough... but the same problem still occurs. (The item in question was initially a different type. An [apparently erroneous] blog post elsewhere suggested that it should be a ListViewItem.)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the `ListView` uses the `SelectedItems` property to keep track of the extended selection. When your collection is bound to the control, it has no way of knowing / updating the `SelectedItems` collection, and therefore doesn't know that there are objects selected. Unfortunately, the `SelectedItems` property is not bindable.

I have in the past created Attached Properties to 'wrap' the `SelectedItems` collection with a bindable property, but it is cumbersome, and I am fairly sure that my implementation might cause leaks.

Alternatively, you can use some minor code-behind / attached property to set the `SelectedItems` property when the `ItemsSource` changes:

**Edit: Changed to Attached Property**

```
public class Bindable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitializeSelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                            "InitializeSelectedItems", typeof(bool), typeof(Bindable), new PropertyMetadata(default(bool), InitializeSelectedItemsChanged));

    private static void InitializeSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject depObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        var listView = depObject as ListBox;

        if (listView != null && (bool)args.NewValue)
        {
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(listView)["ItemsSource"]
                    .AddValueChanged(listView, new EventHandler(ListViewItemsSourceChanged));
        }
    }

    private static void ListViewItemsSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var listView = sender as ListBox;

        listView.SelectedItems.Clear();

        foreach (var item in listView.ItemsSource.OfType<ISelectable>().Where(i => i.IsSelected))
        {
            listView.SelectedItems.Add(item);
        }
    }
}

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableItems}" Bindable.InitializeSelectedItems="True" SelectionMode="Extended" ...>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @andrew-hanlon I was trying to avoid code-behind if possible, but if that's the only option.... :-)

Comment: As I mentioned, you can certainly use a Behavior / Attached property to create a bindable wrapper to the SelectedItems property... however it is tricky to ensure that the collection change event bindings don't cause leaks..

Comment: @RichardJFoster Also, if you only care about initially setting the `SelectedItems` you could move the code-behind above into a reusable attached property - and since all of the event bindings are local, it shouldn't have leaks ;).

Comment: @RichardJFoster I moved the code-behind into an attached property... It should do the trick. You have to make sure to have a common ViewModel Interface that exposes the IsSelected property.

Comment: @AndrewHanlon : When i try to use your code, InitializeSelectedItems is not found in type Bindable. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

A solution will be to store the selected items in a list, or better in a dictionnary, if your listview is a list of items which could be identified as a pair of Key/Value.

Then when your list is updated by the binding, you should iterate through your dictionary and test if a couple key/value exist in the listview you then if true set is property to `Selected`.

It's a way.